# Developing a Julia package using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I have created some functions in **Julia**, which I am willing to develop into a private package registry. Since all my Julia code is in **Jupyter Notebook**, is there any way to develop an Julia package entirely using **Jupyter Notebook**? If so, it would be best if anyone could shed some light on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Nbdev.jl](https://github.com/sapal6/Nbdev.jl) package aims to facilitate this:

https://sapal6.github.io/Nbdev.jl/tutorial/

I also recommend reading this ongoing thread.

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/transforming-a-pluto-notebook-into-a-julia-package/60789